# Удаление пустых строк в конце текстового файла Java

Tags: java, текст, filestream, edittext

Нужно было реализовать логику для замены строки в текстовом файле.Применял разные схемы, но остановился на самом лаконичном, как мне кажется:

```
try {
        Files.write(Paths.get(fileName), Collections.singleton(new String(Files.readAllBytes
                                (Paths.get(fileName))).replace(searchString, replaceString)));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

Все получается хорошо. Но, - после изменения заданной строки, - в конце файла добавляется пустая строка. При добавлении в файл, эта пустая строка мешает,  - не соблюдаются отступы от предыдущего текста, приложение "ругается". Помогите побороть эти пустые строки. По всей видимости, они содержат какой-то tab...

Comment: Попытки побороть приветствуются.

Comment: @Roman C Шутки, это конечно хорошо... Но, я так понимаю, как решить вопрос с удалением пустых строк ВЫ не знаете?

Answer (score 1):

Ответ найден. Просто мне нужно внимательнее читать stackoverflow... Нужно использовать

```
RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile(fileName, "rw");
```